# Creating and printing a list from dates

Tags: list, date, prolog

This is what I've done so far:

```
daycompare(D,D1):-
    parse_time(D,iso_8601,DateCode) @< parse_time(D1,iso_8601,DateCode1).

listdates(P1,P2,D1) :-
    message(P1,P2,D), daycompare(D,D1), print(D) ;
    message(P2,P1,D), daycompare(D,D1), print(D).
```

I'm trying to list out all the dates (D) when (P1) or (P2) message each other. I have so far used the predicate daycompare which compares two dates together and added it within the second one I want to call.

The problem I have is that I have to use the ; to list out subsequent dates that have been found but I want to put it within a list so that I can print it out automatically - I just don't know how.

Here is a sample of my database:

```
message(steve,jessica,'2012-08-05').
message(steve,jessica,'2012-05-17').
message(jessica,steve,'2013-03-15').
message(jessica,steve,'2013-03-23').
message(jessica,steve,'2013-07-23').
```

So if I was to call the rule it would be:

```
listdates(jessica,steve,'2013-08-30').
```

Here is the output from this query:

```
2013-03-15
true ;
2013-03-15
true ;
2013-03-23
true ;
2013-03-23
true ;
2013-07-23
true ;
2013-07-23
true ;
2012-05-17
true ;
2012-05-17
true ;
2012-08-05
true ;
2012-08-05
true ;
false.
```

Another thing I don't get is why the dates are printed out twice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Prolog, predicates aren't functions that return values that you can then assign or use. So `parse_time(D,iso_8601,DateCode) @< parse_time(D1,iso_8601,DateCode1).` isn't meaningful. You want to call them individually, then `DateCode @< DateCode1` or whatever it is you want to compare.

Comment: Like this? daycompare(D,D1):-parse_time(D,iso_8601,DateCode), parse_time(D1,iso_8601,DateCode1),DateCode<DateCode1.

Comment: Yes. By the way, I ran you code as-is, and the dates weren't repeated. So the code you ran when you got those results must be different to the code you're showing.

Comment: Also, if you have a consistent date format, such as `YYYY-MM-DD` where day and month are zero padded to two digits, then you can correctly compare two date strings like `D @< D1` and get expected results. In that case, it will compare the strings per character collating sequence.

Comment: Really that's strange, the code I used and gave are exactly the same. Do you know why mine would be repeating then?

Comment: I ran in SWI Prolog and GNU Prolog. Both did not repeat dates. I copied the code you have above directly in `[user].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Rather than print the dates, you want to return them as a result of the query.
- When you use `parse_time`, the 3rd argument is the result, and those are what you want to compare
- You can use `findall/3` to collect all query results into a list (as @ScottHunter pointed out)

```
daycompare(D,D1):-
    parse_time(D,iso_8601,DateCode),
    parse_time(D1,iso_8601,DateCode1),
    DateCode < DateCode1.

listdates(P1, P2, D1, D) :-
    message(P1, P2, D), daycompare(D, D1) ;
    message(P2, P1, D), daycompare(D, D1).

?- listdates(jessica, steve, '2013-08-30', D).

D = '2013-03-15' ;
D = '2013-03-23' ;
D = '2013-07-23' ;
D = '2012-08-05' ;
D = '2012-05-17'.
```

Since your date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can simplify and get rid of `daycompare` since `@<` will compare the atoms in an order as you would expect:

```
listdates(P1, P2, D1, D) :-
    message(P1, P2, D), D @< D1 ;
    message(P2, P1, D), D @< D1.
```

Then using `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(D, listdates(jessica,steve,'2013-08-30',D), DateList).
DateList = ['2013-03-15', '2013-03-23', '2013-07-23', '2012-08-05', '2012-05-17'].
```

Comment: Wow you made it look so easy, at least I wasn't far off. Thanks everyone for your help I really really appreciate it!

Comment: @Steglas you weren't far off at all. I think the key take-aways are (1) Don't think of prolog predicates as "functions" as in other languages, (2) Prolog generates outputs as part of solving for uninstantiated (unbound) parameters, so you don't have to `write` except in certain cases, (3) `findall` (or `bagof` or `setof`) is a nice tool to gather many solutions that are produced through backtracking of a given predicate.

Comment: One last question. Is it possible to make findall/3 a rule as well? How would that be set out? listdates2(P1,P2,D1,D):-findall(D, listdates(P1,P2,D1,D), DateList). but I only get true.

Comment: Yeah I'm learning both Java and Prolog and I'm finding Java much easier. It's kinda hard to get the concept but I'm sure I will eventually. Yeah I heard of those three tools they're pretty handy - bagof is the more detailed version of findall I recall?

Comment: @Steglas Yes, you can include `findall/3` in a predicate. Nothing special about it that prevents that. What I find with Prolog is that it is actually defined by a small set of simple rules, but the possibilities are great. I think of Prolog versus Java is like comparing the game of Go with the game of Chess.

Answer (score 0):

1. `findall` is what you're looking for to get a list of results.
2. You get a date printed for each different way you've found a solution, so there must be 2 different ways to come up with each of the dates.

Comment: How would I implement the findall function?

Comment: It, or something like it, should be part of the language, depending on which dialect of Prolog you are using.

Comment: I see well I'm using SWI-Prolog. Would it be something like, listdates(P1,P2,D1) :-
    message(P1,P2,D), daycompare(D,D1), findall(D) ;
    message(P2,P1,D), daycompare(D,D1), findall(D). Or is that wrong?

Comment: @Steglas what `findall/3` does for you is, if you have a predicate which provides multiple solutions, it will collect them all into a list for you. But you need at least one free variable in your predicate to return the result of the query rather than having the predicate use `print` to print them out.